# Clicking a Javascript link to make a post request in Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm writing a webscraper/automation tool. This tool needs to use POST requests to submit form data. The final action uses this link:

```
<a id="linkSaveDestination" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("linkSaveDestination", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>Save URL on All Search Engines</a>
```

to submit data from this form:

```
<input name="sem_ad_group__destination_url" type="text" maxlength="1024" id="sem_ad_group__destination_url" class="TextValueStyle" style="width:800px;">
```

I've been using requests and BeautifulSoup. I understand that these libraries can't interact with Javascript, and people recommend Selenium. But as I understand it Selenium can't do POSTs. How can I handle this? Is it possible to do without opening an actual browser like Selenium does?

Comment: Selenium can post just fine. What's important is that you're executing in a runtime that can execute the javascript on the link by clicking it, like that of a webdriver provided by selenium

Comment: You could, of course, just pull the name of the input field(s) for the form and insert whatever values you want and send the post yourself using requests. This would probably be the better option if this is only a small piece of your application that you're not planning on having to do elsewhere.

Comment: So, when I click the link above, it posts what was in the form and refreshes the page. Can I simply make a post request to the same URL instead of using the link? Also, the form has a value attribute when there is data saved for that field, but the input element above shows it without any data entered, so there is no value attribute. Can I just add 'value: "blah"' to my post payload using requests?

Comment: Yes. I've added an answer with some details and a link to documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can absolutely duplicate what the link is doing by just submitting a POST to the proper url (this is, in reality, eventually going to be the same thing that the javascript that fires when the link is clicked does).

You'll find the relevant section in the requests docs here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

So, that'll look something like this for your particular case:

```
payload = {'sem_ad_group__destination_url': 'yourTextValueHere'}
r = requests.post("theActionUrlForTheFormHere", data=payload)
```

If you're having trouble figuring out what url it is actually be posted to, just monitor the network tab (in chrome dev tools) while you manually click the link yourself, you should be able to find the right request and pull any information off of that.

Good Luck!

Comment: Works! Thanks. It's correctly updating the form, but for some reason I get a 500 response code.

Comment: @StevenWerner, if the error code is being truthful, that means the data you're providing in your post is breaking something on the server. Perhaps you're sending bad data?

Comment: I find that sometimes a unique id is associated with the link which must be scraped for and added to the POST.

Answer (score 1):

With `selenium` you mimic the real-user interactions in a real browser - tell it to locate an input, write a text inside, click a button etc - high-level approach - you don't even need to know what is there under-the-hood, you see what a real user sees. The downside here is that there is a real browser involved which, at least, slows things down. You can though, automate a a *headless browser* ([`PhantomJS`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/#git%2Fpy%2Fselenium%2Fwebdriver%2Fphantomjs)), or use a [*`Xvfb` virtual framebuffe*r](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) if you don't have conditions to open up a browser with a UI. Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('url here')

button = driver.find_element_by_id('linkSaveDestination')
button.click()
```

With `requests+BeautifulSoup`, you are going down to the bare metal - using browser developer tools you research/analyze what requests are made to a server and mimic them in your code. Sometimes the way a page is constructed and requests made are too complicated to automate, or there are anti-web-scraping technique used.

There are pros & cons about both approaches - which option to choose depends on many things.

Comment: Thanks, I might try this in the future. I prefer not to have a browser at all, and javascript use is minimal on these pages, so I think I can stick with requests and BeautifulSoup for now